# O que é o elemento "o" criado automaticamente entre meus buttons no HTML?

Tags: html, firefox

Estou desenvolvendo um layout e quando coloco dois buttons um do lado do outro, é criado um elemento "o" no meu HTML, que faz o espaçamento entre os dois, eu conseguiria resolver criando uma `margin` negativa a esquerda, porém gostaria de saber se esse elemento "o" é um bug/recurso do HTML. Não consegui achar nada na internet sobre. Se eu deleto esse elemento, esse espaçamento some e meus botões ficam unidos como eu quero que fique. Segue o link do DotNetFiddle: 
[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R220n5)

Percebi, que o "o" aparece no inspecionar do firefox, mas no do google chrome não.

Comment: Esse HTML tá sendo gerado por alguma _view engine_?

Comment: @LINQ , ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Colocando a seta do mouse em cima do `o` ele exibe [whitespace-only text node](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Como comentado, esta é uma ferramenta de debug do Firefox que exibe espaços em branco entre elementos que possuem `display: inline` por padrão, visto que espaços entre esses elementos são tratados pelos navegadores como espaçamento. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<button>Botão A</button>
<button>Botão B</button>
```

Os botões, por padrão, são exibidos `inline`, porém há uma quebra de linha (que é um *whitespace*) entre eles, então o inspetor do Firefox exibe este símbolo indicando a quebra de linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso auxilia você a fazer o debug de espaçamento de elementos `inline`. Fica mais claro quando utilizado com imagens. Veja o exemplo abaixo onde há duas imagens definidas em linhas distintas. Ao renderizar, existirá um espaçamento entre as mesmas, mesmo não tendo esta definição no CSS.

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
```

Já, se definidas as imagens da mesma linha, o espeçamento deixa de existir. Geralmente fazemos da primeira forma, pois o código fica mais legível, mas como não definimos o CSS, não esperamos que exista tal espaçamento. Desta forma, o inspetor do Firefox nos auxilia a encontrar a fonte deste comportamento.

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
```

Se você definir os botões na mesma linha, verá que o inspetor não exibe este caractere:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O espaçamento ainda existirá pois é o estilo padrão do botão.

Comment: quebra de linha ou white-space?

Answer (score 6):

Segundo [essa](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/) postagem no blog do [Firefox Nightly](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org) esse `o` é gerado automaticamente pelo navegador ao analisar seu Html e encontrar espaços em branco.

Sempre que o Firefox encontrar um dos seguintes caracteres ele criará um novo nó dentro do DOM:

> - "\t" TAB \u0009
> - "\n" LF  \u000A
> - "\r" CR  \u000D
> - " "
> - SPC \u0020

Por exemplo, dado o seguinte trecho HTML:

```
<!-- My document -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

O firefox irá gerar a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Representação do DOM]

Os nós em verde podem ter largura e altura diferente de 0, o que pode gerar espaçamento indesejável no seu layout, esse `o` é utilizado para ajudar na depuração,facilitando a busca desses pontos

Fonte da imagem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM