# Não consigo colocar uma div colada na outra

Tags: html, css

Eu quero colocar as 3 `divs` na mesma linha com `width: 33.3333%`, mas está aparecendo um espaço entre elas. Note na imagem que o `padding`, `margin` e `borda` estão zerados, e eu declarei `box-sizing:border-box` no `reset`.

[image: Análise de código fonte no Chrome para desenvolvedor]

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
            a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
            del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
            small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
            b, u, i, center,
            dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
            fieldset, form, label, legend,
            table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
            article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
            figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
            menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
            time, mark, audio, video {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    border: 0;
                    font-size: 100%;
                    font: inherit;
                    vertical-align: baseline;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
            }
```

Não sei de onde saiu essa barda se o próprio navegador não diz nada pelo inspetor de elementos. Alguém sabe como posso remover isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, como já dito display `inline-block` possui um espaçamento que mesmo zerando todas a margens ainda assim continua com espaços.

Como eu posso resolver isso com os elementos ainda sendo `inline-block`?
Simples. só zerar o `font-size: 0` do elemento pai. faz sentido? não sei mas assim resolve, segue exemplo:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}

nav{
  font-size: 0;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 33.333%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>
```

No meu exemplo o elemento pai é a tag `nav`, porém existe outra forma de resolver isso, olhe o exemplo:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 33.333%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">One</a
  ><a href="#">Two</a
  ><a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>
```

Observe que agora não zerei o `font-size` do elemento pai, mas o carácter `>` do fechamento de cada tag pulei e logo já iniciei a próxima tag...

o que aconteceu foi deixar praticamente tudo na mesma linha, e observando essa comportamento fica claro que aquele espaço nos elementos `inline-block` é causado pela quebra de linha no código, não faz sentido mas beleza

Comment: Achei que já tinha visto de tudo, aí vem você com essa. Ou melhor "essas". As duas soluções não tem nenhum sentido! Mas se funciona é isso que vale. Valeu pela dica. Agora, acho que nunca mais vou sofrer pra colocar os elementos na mesma linha. Grande abraço!

Comment: não faz mesmo kk só de vc pular a linha no código visualmente fica com aquele espaço do demonio, felizmente tem como resolver

Answer (score 1):

Elementos `inline-block` por padrão possuem espaços, isso é algum tipo convenção, não sei ao certo, para remover esses espaços basta setar uma `margin` negativa, exemplo

```css
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>
```

A propósito, sua solução é a melhor possível, `display flex`, ou melhor `flexbox` é para mim o melhor jeito de comportar os elementos no layout, segue o guia completo [Flexbox css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Eu havia esquecido dessa regra que o `inline-blok` adicionava uma margin de 4px a direita. \0/   Só lembrei agora depois que eu li sua resposta. Mas de qualquer forma, acho que vou ficar mesmo com o `display flex` porque é mais fácil. Valeu!!!

Answer (score 0):

Eu coloquei `display:flex;` na div pai e resolveu meu problema. Valeu! Mas se mesmo assim algem puder me explicar esse questão vai ser bom saber. Isso me deixou com "uma pulga atrás da orelha". Penso que as div deveriam ficar uma ao lado da outra uma vez que eu zerei tudo e pedi `display:inline-block;` e `width:33.3333%;`.[image: display:flex; CSS]

Comment: Essa é a solução ou uma nova duvida?

Comment: Eu acredito que essa seja a solução não seja a solução ideal. Mas se alguém pudesse me dizer porque estava aparecendo uma borda, eu gostaria muito de saber.

Comment: Acho que tem a ver com essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212245/53279), mas não tenho certeza por que está usando o Chrome, no firefox fica mais fácil de identificar isso